# flatpickr configuration - how to set a default date of today's date for a new record but retain stored value when updating an existing record

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, flatpickr

I am successfully inserting or updating a date record using flatpickr.  With a new record the default is 1/1/1970 but I want to make the default date for a new record today's date. See code below.  Initially I only used the code that is now in the "else" part of the statement but this reset the date on any record being edited to today's date.  So second idea was to test if this is an existing record in which case the first two lines of the "if" statement work or if it is a new record then the "else" set's defaultDate to today.  Current behaviour with this code is that adding and editing is working fine but on a new record the default date is 1/1/1970 not today's date. Thank you

```
if ($("#date_record_created").length > 0) 
{
    $("#date_record_created").flatpickr({
    enableTime: false,
    dateFormat: "d-M-Y"//"d-m-Y"//"F, d Y" 
    //minDate: "01-Jan-2012"
    });
}  
else 
{
    $("#date_record_created").flatpickr({
    enableTime: false,
    dateFormat: "d-M-Y",//"d-m-Y"//"F, d Y"
    defaultDate: "today",
    dateFormat: "d-M-Y"    
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
defaultDate: new Date()
```

should do the trick. It points the defaultDate value to a new JavaScript Date object that, by default, holds the current date. (See below)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for the current date and time according to system settings for timezone offset.

Comment: Thank you athrir,
This almost works!  thank you for steering me in the right direction.  The issue now is that I cannot get both the existing date if an existing record and the default date if a new record.  So I guess it is the  `if ($("#date_record_created").length > 0)`  that is not working.
The following provides todays date for new and existing records

   ` $("#date_record_created").flatpickr({
      enableTime: false,
      dateFormat: "d-M-Y",//"d-m-Y"//"F, d Y"
      defaultDate: new Date()//defaultDate: "today",
      });`

Comment: This provides the existing date or 01/01/1970 
    if ($("#date_record_created").length > 0) 
     {
        $("#date_record_created").flatpickr({
         enableTime: false,
         dateFormat: "d-M-Y"//"d-m-Y"//"F, d Y" 
         });
        }  
     else 
     {
      $("#date_record_created").flatpickr({
      enableTime: false,
      dateFormat: "d-M-Y",//"d-m-Y"//"F, d Y"
      defaultDate: new Date(),//defaultDate: "today",
      });
     };

Comment: Thank you in advance for your thoughts
- my jquery is not great but I tried `alert($("#date_record_created").length);` and this shows "1" for both new and existing records

Comment: `if ($("#date_record_created").length > 0) ` is checking if there's any element with id="date_record_created" loaded in the document. Depending on the desired logic, you might want to change your if statement to check if there's already a created record or if you're creating a new one. If you can explain your intent further I might be able to help you more

Comment: thank you atherir - my intention to is to check whether I have arrived on this page 1) to create a new record   or   2) to edit an existing record

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `if` statement is behaving the way you desire? Can you maybe post a jsfiddle or a codepen with a reproduction of your code?

Comment: hi - I have created this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/paul724/bzn7pemu/26/      but I do not know in jsfiddle how to mimic the production environment with records to test the if statement.  In the fiddle it defaults to todays date - in production environment for a new record it defaults to 01-01-1970.  Please see the js fiddle Javascript box for some notes